# How to call upon Facebook from app delegate

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have been struggling mightily for the last 5 hours trying to implement Facebook into my app and it has been a COMPLETE pain. I am now going step by step based on the Facebook site. I have implemented everything as they have said but I am confused as to how I can call upon Facebook from another view controller (ex. bring up the login screen and then have the user post something to there wall).

This how I have done it. If anyone can please take the time to explain I will forever been in your debt, I am losing my mind. Thanks

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"XXXXXXXXXX" andDelegate:fbControl];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] 
        && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
        facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
        facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    }

    if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
        [facebook authorize:nil];
    }

}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {

    return [facebook handleOpenURL:url];
}

- (void)fbDidLogin {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];

    [facebook dialog:@"feed" andDelegate:self];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you've done is enabling interaction with the Facebook app, there is no code in there that actually makes your app interact. For example, I have this in one of my apps:

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   FACEBOOK_APP_ID, @"app_id",
                                   self.newsItem.link, @"link",
                                   self.newsItem.imageURL, @"picture",
                                   self.newsItem.title, @"caption",
                                   contentString, @"description",
                                   nil];

AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

[appDelegate.facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:(id)self];
```

This shows a dialog which lets the user post something on their wall. What method you need to call depends on what you want to do, but `dialog:andParams:andDelegate` is used to display a "post to news feed" dialog.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I'm getting an error saying "newsItem" not found? Thanks again

Comment: Yeah, newsItem was an object in my app. You need to replace those values with your own values.